# Combinatorial proof of $1=\sum_{i=0}^n{(-1)^i \binom{n}{i} 2^{n-i}}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm searching for a combinatorial proof of the following equality:
$$1=\sum_{i=0}^n{(-1)^i \binom{n}{i} 2^{n-i}}$$
It's trivial to show using Newton's binomial theorem: $(-1+2)^n=1$, but I'm interested in a direct combinatorial explanation of this fact, without any simplifications.

I see the term ${\binom{n}{i} 2^{n-i}}$ as an ordered pair of a subset of size $i$ (from a set of size $n$) and a subset of varying length of the remaining elements in the set, but the orderdness and the $(-1)^i$ got me stuck in this line of thought.

Comment: Do you mean $(-1)^i $?

Comment: @MarcusM Indeed. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

We can prove this using the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.  For each subset $S \subset [n]$, let $f_S$ be the number of subsets of $[n]$ that contain $S$.  Then note that $f_S = 2^{n - |S|}$.  The principle of inclusion exclusion then tells us that the number of subsets containing precisely $0$ elements is $$ \sum\limits_{S \subseteq [n]} (-1)^{|S|} f_S = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n \sum\limits_{\substack{S \subseteq [n]\\ |S| = i}} (-1)^i 2^{n - i} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} 2^{n-i}.$$

However, since there is only one set with $0$ elements---namely the empty set---this quantity must be equal to $1$.

Comment: Why is the number of subsets containing $0$ elements equal to $\sum\limits_{S \subseteq [n]} (-1)^{|S|} f_S$?

Comment: [The Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) tells us that.

Comment: I mean, what are the sets AiAi we are applying the Inclusion-Exlusion principle to? How are the subsets containing precisely 0 elements are the union of them while fSfS are their intersection?

Comment: @NightRa, In combinatorics, there is a much generalized version of inclusion-exclusion that isn't just for counting the cardinality of unions.  I'd rather not develop the whole theory here; it's the core of Chapter 2 of Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 1*, which is available online here:  http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1/